# using one function for multiple entries javascript

Tags: javascript

im trying to take multiple inputs from a user with different element id's and run them through one if else function. here is my code:

Enter the grade and number of credits for course 1:

```
<input type="text" id="lettergrade1" onchange="lettergrade[0]=numgrade(this.value)";>
<input type="text" id="credithour1" onchange="credhour[0]";>
```

etc... this extends down to lettergrade 5. I have to run them through the function numgrade (without using a for loop). how do I run these through the same if else construct without making 5 different ones (how can I make one statement that will work for 5 diffferent id's)?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the elements and bind them to the onchange callback:

```js
var $ = document;
var lettergrade = [];

[].slice.call($.querySelectorAll('.lettergrade')).forEach(function(el, index) {
  el.onchange = function() {
    numgrade(index, this.value);
  }
});

function numgrade(index, value) {
  lettergrade[index] = value;
  
  $.getElementById('output').innerText = JSON.stringify(lettergrade);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="lettergrade" id="lettergrade1" placeholder="1">
<input type="text" class="lettergrade" id="lettergrade2" placeholder="2">
<input type="text" class="lettergrade" id="lettergrade3" placeholder="3">
<input type="text" class="lettergrade" id="lettergrade4" placeholder="4">
<input type="text" class="lettergrade" id="lettergrade5" placeholder="5">
    
<output id="output"></output>
```